# Was bedeutet hier "historisch gesehen"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Der Wert des Geldes ist so manipulierbar geworden wie niemals zuvor. Das macht uns Angst.
>
> Historisch gesehen, ist der Glaube, dass unser Geldsystem langfristig immer so bleibt, wie es heute ist, eine Illusion. Durch nichts belegbar.

Bedeutet "historisch gesehen" hier aus der Sicht der Historiker, oder bedeutet es "die historischen wirtschaftlichen Veranstaltungen haben bewiesen, dass ..."?

Comment: *In der Rückschau* wäre hier eine passende Alternative. Es geht nicht um *harte* Geschichtswissenschaft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Der Satz bedeutet, dass man bei Betrachtung der geschichtlichen Entwicklung (also durch Vergleich der vergangenen Situation mit der gegenwärtigen) feststellen kann, dass der Glaube an ein unveränderliches Geldsystem nicht gerechtfertigt ist.

Anders gesagt: Das Geldsystem verändert sich im Lauf der Zeit. Wer trotzdem glaubt es bliebe konstant, muss nur den Zustand der Vergangenheit mit dem Zustand der Gegenwart vergleichen um sich vom Gegenteil zu überzeugen.